# Model is completely messed up after training on training set after using train_test_split

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

Data set is generated like this:

```
from numpy.random import normal
def make_labels(X, f, noise=0) :
   return map(lambda x : f(x) + (normal(0,noise) if noise>0 else 0), X)

def make_instances(x1, x2, N) :
return np.array([np.array([x]) for x in np.linspace(x1,x2,N)])

def f(x):
   return 5 + x - 2 * x**2 - 5 * x**3

X = make_instances(-5, 5, 50)
y_map = make_labels(X, f, 200)
y = np.array(list(y_map))
```

My task is to code train function and then train model on original set and on split set. This is my train function:

```
def train(X, y, d):
  poly = sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures(d)
  phi = poly.fit_transform(X)
  w = np.matmul(np.linalg.pinv(phi), y)
  h = np.matmul(phi, w)
  return h
```

First I trained model on original data set like this (with polynomial features degree = 3 for example):

```
h = train(X, y, 3)
```

And result was like this:

```
plt.grid()
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, h, 'r')
```

[train_on_original_set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNgUG.png)

But when I split data using train_test_split like this and after that train model on train set:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.5)
h_train = train(X_train, y_train, 3)
```

Result is weird:

```
plt.grid()
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X_train, h_train, 'r')
```

[train_on_train_set_after_split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbWOs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put shuffle=False. As stated here it is True by default:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split